# Transaction to 0xcd48a86666D2a79e027D82cA6Adf853357c70d02 on Goerli-testnet keeps on failing

Tags: ethers.js, goerli

I try to send Eth to Weth (using code below) and it keeps on failing and I have no idea what I am doing wrong (or what I might have forgotten).

```
const exchangeEth = async () => {
const gasPrice = await providerTestnet.getGasPrice();
const valueHuman = "0.0035";
const txBuild = {
    from: myAddress,
    to: "0xcd48a86666D2a79e027D82cA6Adf853357c70d02",
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(valueHuman),
    nonce: await providerTestnet.getTransactionCount(myAddress, "latest"),
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    gasPrice: gasPrice};

    const txSend = await walletSigner.sendTransaction(txBuild);
    console.log(txSend);
}
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction>

Thx,
Peter

btw, this is tx-hash on goerli etherscan:0x6f33c9b1f6fc30bed0b73220dba90e1a0cd5a53d340c8f73c8ecaa0fe60f82ff

Answer (score 0):

address was token address not the contract address.

Instead of the address in my question, I used this address "0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6" which has a contract. The address is the question is the address of a token. I am an absolute beginner in this, but the contract sends weth back when it receives eth. I need to dig a bit deeper into this about the why and why not (interesting stuff).